# Cloud Firestore user private documents in a shared collection

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

### Problem

I am fairly new to NoSQL database design, and I am looking to leverage Google's [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) for a new app I am creating. Looks easy and neat.

In my data model I have `users` and `pages`. A user can own many pages. Users can link their accounts to other users (think like a family plan). Linked users will have one leader user, and all other users are followers. With this design, all followers get access to the leader user's pages. Followers can create, read, update, and delete pages in the name of the leader. As a net effect, all linked users share pages. I think the structure will look like this.

```
/database/
    users/
        [user-doc]
    pages/
        [page-doc]
```

### Constraints to help shape the problem

- I envision starting with roughly 10 to 50 thousand users, possibly breaking 100 thousand later.
- I envision each user owning about 30-40 pages on average.
- I will limit linked users to a maximum of 5 users. That is, one leader and four followers.

### Things I am wondering...

One thing I would like to confirm is this design a good one, specifically in the context of Cloud Firestore.

1. For the security rules, when a user wants to R/U/D a `page` doc the user's permissions are checked by seeing if the `user` owns that `page`, or if that `user` is a 'follower' type account and the leader the owner of the `page`. Is this fair?
2. Each `page` doc's identifier will be auto-generated by Firestore ([as mentioned here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)). In order to retrieve all pages owned by a `user` (or the linked leader), is it as simple as querying `db.collection("pages").whereEqualTo.("page-owner", uid)`? Where the `uid` is the user's unique ID. If there are 100,000 users, and each user has 40 pages, is this query going to be efficient?

I really appreciate the input! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes, queries scale with the size of the result set, not the size of the collection.